# How to get the dropdowns in jquery to work for the subsequent times without any on change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a main textbox(Months), on the change of which, a dropdown menu is created for another textbox(Days). Once I have these populated, I save it. Now when I go back to edit it, I directly want to change the option in the Days textbox, but since the dropdown of Days is triggered on change of the textbox "Months" I do not get the dropdown of days. 
The following is my code:

```
 function editValues() {
  //initializations
    $('.Months').on("change", function(){
    monthsValueSet = this.value;

   //pass monthsValueSet to database to retrieve values 
   $('.Days').html("");

   for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
   $('.Days').append('<option>' + data[i].days  + '</option');
   }

  });
  }
 //code for Save button
 //code for edit
 $("#daysMonthsTable").on("click", ".edit-months", function(event){
 editValues();
 });
```

My HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
 <td>
   <div class="Months">
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td><label>Months</label></td>
  <td ><input type="text" class="Months"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>                           
 </div>
 </td>

 <td>
 <div class = "Days">
 <table>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td><label>Days</label></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="Days"></td>
  </tr>                                         
 </tbody>
  </table>                           
 </div>
 </td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand your problem, but if I got it right then you need to make sure that all of your triggers are locked on elements which you do not change in your update...

Answer (score 0):

Do following

```
$("#daysMonthsTable").on("click", ".edit-months", function(event){
   editValues();
  $('.Months').trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: I tried `.trigger` but it doesnt help. When I manually go change the months field, it does obviously get the on change event and gives me the dropdown for Days